# Filtering all items of specific type (ref document)

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, meanjs

I am trying to query all `inventory.products` that are of `inventory.product.type` computers. I am not sure how to do this. I have read the documentation and have tried a few but it seems like: `db.inventory.products.find({type: { code: {$in: ['computers'] } } })` would be the proper way but never get back any products of the type.

The reason I am building my query in mongo prompt is so I can move it to my service when I have success.

Any advice?

### Inventory.Product

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProductSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Name is required'
  },
  type: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Inventory.Product.Type',
    required: 'Product type is required'
  },
});

mongoose.model('Inventory.Product', ProductSchema);
```

### Inventory.Product.Type

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProductTypeSchema = new Schema({
  code: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Please enter name',
    trim: true
  },
});

mongoose.model('Inventory.Product.Type', ProductTypeSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to create a method in my service like so:

```
service.autoCompleteType = function(query) {
  var productList = null;
  var products = [];

  return Product
    .find()
    .populate('type')
    .exec()
    .then(function(products){
      productList = products;
    })
    .then(function(quantities){
      for (var i in productList) {
        if (productList[i].type.code === query) {
          products.push(productList[i]);
        }
      }
    return products;
  });
};
```

This allowed me to query `type.code` as required and returned everything matching `query`